# UITableViewController loadView instantiated view controller with identifier from storyboard, but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, console, crash

I written rest of the app programming is built without storyboard needs, until I has built one storyboard for quiz. Rest of the app is built in UITableView, but Quiz is UIViewController. However, My app has crashed after tap UITableView Cell to enter Quiz.

Console say:

*2021-04-14 10:11:01.879615-0500 Deaf Can Code[9790:40235755] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "SwiftQuiz" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204219d4 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f514ca -[UITableViewController loadView] + 666
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f62947 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f630c1 -[UIViewController view] + 27
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f7b017 -[UIViewController _setPresentationController:] + 100
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f72cc4 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1409
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f76817 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4942
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f7765a __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 98
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f77990 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 519
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f775b8 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f77a46 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 155
13  Deaf Can Code                       0x000000010b190881 $s13Deaf_Can_Code15SwiftControllerC9tableView_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableG0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 1249
14  Deaf Can Code                       0x000000010b1909e7 $s13Deaf_Can_Code15SwiftControllerC9tableView_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableG0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 167
15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248b1a43 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1078
16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248b15f6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 97
17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248b1f42 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 334
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24b9107a -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 54
19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246a5954 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 333
20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246959fc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 221
21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c72ac _afterCACommitHandler + 85
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f1f8 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20389a77 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 547
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a01a __CFRunLoopRun + 1113
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
26  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c257db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24696cf7 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2469bba8 UIApplicationMain + 101
29  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff551885f2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
30  Deaf Can Code                       0x000000010b19964a $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
31  Deaf Can Code                       0x000000010b1995be $s13Deaf_Can_Code11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
32  Deaf Can Code                       0x000000010b199699 main + 41
33  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025a3e9 start + 1
34  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "SwiftQuiz" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro (7AED4D26-EE84-4240-9C7D-5E29DF258476) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro*

Libsystem kernel says:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x7fff61131458 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x7fff6113145d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff61131460 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x7fff61131462 <+10>: jae    0x7fff6113146c            ; <+20>. // Error: Thread 1: "-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier \"SwiftQuiz\" from storyboard \"Main\", but didn't get a UITableView." 
    0x7fff61131464 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff61131467 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff6112b6a1            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff6113146c <+20>: retq   
    0x7fff6113146d <+21>: nop    
    0x7fff6113146e <+22>: nop    
    0x7fff6113146f <+23>: nop
```

Here my storyboard:
[image]

Have you know any idea to fix this issues, thank you! :)

Comment: If you write a subclass of UITableViewController, it's view must be a UITableView. If your UIViewController subclass's view isn't a UITableView, then it can't be a subclass of UITableViewController, just a regular UIViewController subclass

Comment: Well I used class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ... } in all the projects.

Comment: Go look in the "Main" storyboard: view controller with identifier "SwiftQuiz", Its class is set to something that subclasses UITableView. Select its view: What is the type of its view in the storyboard? It needs to be a UITableView not a UIView

Comment: If I changed that code to 
   
 let Swift: Void? = navigationController?.pushViewController(SwiftQuizTestViewController() as UIViewController, animated: true)
                  
 return Swift!
   
 This will casued crashed and console say: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Deaf_Can_Code/SwiftQuizViewController.swift, line 280
2021-04-14 11:48:03.342395-0500 Deaf Can Code[10118:40292158] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Deaf_Can_Code/SwiftQuizViewController.swift, line 280

Comment: It seem it worked to connect View Controller, but in however it was failed to displayed those label and buttons from storyboard

Comment: You can't instantiate a VC defined in storyboard using just init, i.e. MyVC(), you won't get the view loaded from the storyboard properly. You need to check the type of SwiftQuizViewController's view in the storyboard is a UITableView (not a UIView) because SwiftQuizViewController's is a UITableViewController not a UIViewController. If you mean for it to be a UIView, then make SwiftQuizViewController be a UIVIewController not a UITableViewController

Comment: Werid, other project of my app is half code and storyboard so it was work as well with full of UIViewController and UItableView so I have no idea why it was first issues for me.